# Bash SIGUSR1 loop script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, signals

I started learning bash 3-4 days ago and I have a task to do that I'm having hard time completing. I need to make a script, running a loop which after being signaled SIGUSR1, it should print the process id and exit. I'd be very thankful if i receive some help.

Comment: Can you update your post with your code so far?

Comment: All I've written isn't even close to what the end result should be. Not much sense pasting code

Comment: Look up the `trap` and `exit` commands, and the special parameter `$$`.

Comment: @p0int Well then add a `trap` command that just outputs something when `SIGUSR1` was received. From that starting point continue. Also make sure you understand shell quoting and what "a word" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do it this way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Our USR1 signal handler
usr1_trap(){
    printf 'Here is the PID: %d\nExiting right-now!\n' $$
    exit
}

# Register USR1 signal handler
trap usr1_trap USR1

printf 'Run this to stop me:\nkill -USR1 %d\n' $$

# Wait in background, not consuming CPU
while :; do
   sleep 9223372036854775807 & # int max (2^63 - 1)
   wait $!
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but when I enter the kill command with the pid, nothing happens. I'm still stuck in the code. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @p0int What is your shell/OS name? `zsh` which is MacOS shell does not know `infinity` with `sleep`. So give it a large integer value instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `trap` command to execute a command when the signal was recieved:

```sh
trap 'echo "Hmm, SIGUSR1??!"' SIGUSR1
```

To make the code cleaner let's do this with a function:

```sh
exit_program(){
    echo "Here is the PID: $$"
    exit
}
```

How to call the function in trap?

```sh
trap "exit_program" SIGUSR1
```

Hope this would be helpful:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Cancel Program
exit_program(){
    echo "Here is the PID: $$"
    exit
}

# Reciever
trap "exit_program" SIGUSR1
```